# Storing and evaluating expressions in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm working on an app where the end user designs a form, which is just a simple table. The user can define the number the rows and columns and set some properties for each cell. So it is somewhat similar to a spreadsheet. The user then creates reports. The form serves as a template for reports, which have to obide the form structure and the user is allowed to enter values in cells. Each report has to have one, and only one, form on which it is based on. The tricky part is that the user can define any of the cells in the form to be an arithmetic expression involving other cells in the form. Again, similar to writing a formula in a spreadsheet. A report using this form does not allow the user to enter the value for cells with an expression, but has to automatically calculate the value of the cell by evaluating the expression. I need to store both forms and reports in a multi-user database. At any time a user can change the form. If he changes an expression for one or more cells, all reports based on this form have to be recalculated accordingly. The DB has to be able to handle dozens of forms and several million reports.

A simple domain model in C# would go as follows:

```
enum CellType { Value, Expression }

class FormCell : 
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public CellType Type { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
    public double NumericalValue { get; set; }
    // Holds the expression
    public string Formula { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Form : 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FormType Type { get; set; }
    public List<FormCell> Cells { get; set; }

    public Form()
    {
        Cells = new List<FormCell>();
    }
}

 class Report : 
{
    public Form Form { get; set; }
    public List<FormCell> ValueCells { get; set; }

    public Report(Form form)
    {
        this.Form = form;
        // Copy the value cells (cells with constant values, not expressions) from the form to the report
        this.ValueCells = new List<FormCell>(form.Cells.Where(c => c.Type == CellType.Value)).ConvertAll(c=>new FormCell(c));
        // TODO: Figure out how to evaluate cells with expressions
    }
}
```

With no prior exposure to NoSQL databases, I started down to usual path of relational databases, stored procs and dynamic SQL and, as could be expected, it is a nightmare. I'm really impressed with RavenDB and I was wondering whether this could be done in RavenDB and if so, how exactly? Thank you.

Comment: Why can't the reports be calculated "on-the-fly"? Are you asking if (and how) you should calculate the cell values when the report is stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, but also if and how the reports could be recalculated whenever a user changes a formula (expression) in the form. In a relational db you would be probably do this with triggers and stored procedures. I know that RavenDB has a great change tracking mechanism. What I don't know is if there is a way to store and evaluate expressions within the database. One solution would be to develop a server app which would subscribe to changes, recalculate the values and store the results back to the database, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the database itself.